# Return specific row and desc order in sql in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i want my query to return a specific row of the table where a column contains specific value first and with year desc.

if i have table something like this

Table employee

```
 id  - Name    -    Year - Status 
  1  - Ashish  -    2016 - Old
  2  - Srisan  -    2017 - New
  3  - Mohit   -    2018 - New
  4  - Ram     -    2015 - Old
  5  - Boby    -    2016 - New
```

then result should be

```
 id -  Name   -  Year - Status 
  3 -  Mohit  -  2018 - New
  2 -  Srisan -  2017 - New
  5 -  Boby   -  2016 - New
  1 -  Ashish -  2016 - Old
  4 -  Ram    -  2015 - Old
```

Where Status is new and sort via desc of Year

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: ORDER BY status = 'new' DESC, or see FIELD()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select * from tablename
order by case when 'New' then 0 else 1 end, year desc
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted here ? if there is any problem you should explain the reason behind your downvote - otherwise how anyone can correct his mistake - at least SO user should have some manner

Answer (score 3):

Sort by `FIELD(Status)` and `Year`

```
SELECT id, Name, Year, Status 
FROM myTable
ORDER BY FIELD(Status, 'New', 'Old'), Year DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

For expected result as mentioned in your question, query would be

```
SELECT * FROM employee  ORDER BY Status ASC, Year DESC;
```

it has all rows but if you want specific rows then you have to use Where clause as mentioned below as per your required condition.

```
SELECT Name FROM employee where Year=2018 ORDER BY Year DESC;
```

Comment: The question was to sort by `status` first, then year. :-)